# Get object in observable

Tags: angular, observable, angularfire2

I have this code that goes through a list of type Product.

```
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="produtos != null">
  <label class="form-control-label" for="produto">Produto</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="produto" (change)="setProduto($event.target.value)" name="produto">
        <option value="" selected="">selecione</option>
        <option *ngFor="let produto of produtos | async" [value]="produto">
            NF: {{ produto.nNF }}
         </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I need to get the object type "product" and move to a function in my component.

But I can not. I get the object but I can not traverse the attributes.

This is my component:

```
public produtos: Observable<Produto[]>;
retrieveProdutos(cnpjFornecedor: string) {
this.produtos = this.srv.getProdutos(cnpjFornecedor)
}
```

My service:

```
    getProdutos(cnpjFornecedor: string): Observable<Produto[]> {
    return this.db.list(this.pt.pathProduto, {
    query: {
    orderByChild: 'fornecedor/cnpj',
    equalTo: cnpjFornecedor
    }
    });

}
```

My model

```
export class Produto {
public nNF: string;
public data: string;
public peso: number;
public precoCompra: number;
public desconto: number;
public urlNota: string;
public vendido: boolean;
public adm: string;
public fornecedor: any;
}
```

Comment: How do you get `produtos` in your component? Could you please show those.

Comment: It is received through a FirebaseListObservable <Produto[]>. I can get the value inside '{{}}' but I can not move to another function.

Comment: Could you show a sample element in `produtos` list which you get inside your component?

Comment: What do you mean by 'move to another function'?

Comment: I added more information to the question. I need to pass the entire Pessoa selected object to a function in my component.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try changing your model to this,

```
export interface Produto {
 nNF: string;
 data: string;
 peso: number;
 precoCompra: number;
 desconto: number;
 urlNota: string;
 vendido: boolean;
 adm: string;
 fornecedor: any;
}
```

Also are you sure you will have a property value available and assigned for each of these properties of `Produto`. If not, mark the that are ones optional by adding `?`. Like for example, if `desconto` and `vendido` are optional, mark it like this,

```
export interface Produto {
 nNF: string;
 data: string;
 peso: number;
 precoCompra: number;
 desconto?: number;
 urlNota: string;
 vendido?: boolean;
 adm: string;
 fornecedor: any;
}
```

See if that changes anything.

Comment: I need Produto to be a class.

Comment: Could you show what this returns `return this.db.list(this.pt.pathProduto, {
    query: {
    orderByChild: 'fornecedor/cnpj',
    equalTo: cnpjFornecedor
    }
    });`? At least one sample element of this list?